# Numpy slice to indices

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 3x3 matrix. The 1D indices of this matrix are:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Is there a function that receives a slice and returns the 1D indices, wathever the dimension? Something like:

```
m = np.ones((3, 3))
id1 = some_function(m, (1, :))  # [3, 4, 5]
id2 = some_function(m, (:, 1))  # [1, 4, 7]

# Use the indices together
m[id1 + id2] = wathever
m[~(id1 + id2)] = wathever else
```

I don't want to code it because I'm sure it exists somewhere in numpy! For those who wonder why I want that, it's because I want to merge several slices together, use not (~) on the indices, etc.

Comment: IIUC you are losing the 1D indices info once you slice. So, don't think that's possible, unless you might store how you are slicing, e..g in this case you are slicing across rows or cols, so you can store the row/col indices as `slicing-info` to retrieve back the 1D indices.

Comment: Even if you had such a function, it wouldn't work like you want. Even `m[id1]` wouldn't do what you want; NumPy interprets that as indexing along the first axis, not along the flattened array. `id1+id2` also wouldn't do what you're looking for, and `~` doesn't do what you're trying to make it do for integer indices.

Comment: Sorry, my premise was wrong and this question doesn't make much sense anymore. I'll read the answer(s) and possibly delete it.

Answer (score 2):

`ravel_multi_index` returns the 1d equivalent of n-d indexing tuple:

```
In [208]: np.ravel_multi_index(([1],[0,1,2]),(3,3))
Out[208]: array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
In [209]: np.ravel_multi_index(([0,1,2],[1]),(3,3))
Out[209]: array([1, 4, 7], dtype=int32)
```

For more complex indexing we may need to use `ix_` to get index broadcasting right:

```
In [214]: np.ravel_multi_index((np.ix_([0,1,2],[1,2])),(3,3))
Out[214]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

Now we just need to turn `[1,:]` in to that tuple.  Something in `indexing_tricks` should do that.

```
In [222]: np.ravel_multi_index((np.ix_(np.r_[0:3],[1,2])),(3,3))
Out[222]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]], dtype=int32)
In [223]: np.ravel_multi_index((np.ix_([1],np.r_[0:3])),(3,3))
Out[223]: array([[3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

In a more general case we'd want to use `m.shape` instead of `(3,3)`.

`~` works on boolean masks, not indices.  So to 'delete' the [1] element from a array, we can do:

```
In [225]: mask = np.ones((3,),bool)
In [226]: mask[1] = False       # index to delete
In [227]: np.arange(3)[mask]
Out[227]: array([0, 2])
```

This is essentially what `np.delete` does.